# Magento 1: Cron fatal error in app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, cron, ce-1.8.1.0, fatal-error

One of my client's CRON daemon recently started sending those errors:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on a
>   non-object in
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php on line 105

Running Magento 1.8.1.0

This corresponds to the following lines:

```
$this->_pendingSchedules = Mage::getModel('cron/schedule')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::STATUS_PENDING)
            ->load();
```

I've already ensured that the `Mage_Cron_Model_Resource_Schedule_Collection` class exists and the file is at the right location.

I've also checked the `cron_schedule` table and cron is running fine, most of the scheduled job are in the `success` status and there's a few `pending` jobs as well.

I'm not quite sure where I should start debugging. **Any clue where I should start looking to narrow down the issue ?**

Comment: You should start by asking your client what on Earth he has done... But yes technically, check if a module hasn't been installed, or if a file hasn't been deleted by mistake

Comment: @Mayers yep that's what I will do but I was thinking maybe it's a known Magento issue and it has nothing to do with the client ^^

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The reason addFieldToFilter freaks out, is probably because your getCollection returns NULL. Make sure there is also a `Cron/Model/Resource/Schedule` folder. Otherwise, it's hard to tell what could exactly cause this without more context. But check when the cron last ran properly, something changed at that time

Comment: @Mayers yes I checked that and it's all good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in question is:

```
        $this->_pendingSchedules = Mage::getModel('cron/schedule')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::STATUS_PENDING)
            ->load();
```

Based on that, your problem is that `getCollection()` is not returning the object Magento expects. Is anything overriding `cron/schedule`, or its collection `cron/resource_schedule_collection`?

I would suggest adding logging in there to determine the exact type (`get_class($var)`) of `Mage::getModel('cron/schedule')` and `Mage::getModel('cron/schedule')->getCollection()` in that context. That should give you an idea of where to proceed. Let it run, see what comes out.

It's hard to speculate about the root cause without more info. I suspect a problem with configuration (module XML), either a file being broken, or some module overriding or replacing some XML it shouldn't.

Comment: Imma add some logs and see what's up